# Why do my displays work only as long as I don't change anything?

Tags: video, boot

Here's a weird problem I've been having with two old computers. One is a Pentium III 500; the other is a Celeron 700.

Both of them work fine until I change something, anything. Then they won't boot, and I get no video.

So, I get disgusted and put them away for a few days. When I try them again, they're fine!

They stay fine, unless I change something. Then it happens all over again. What's causing this?

Comment: This requires a good number more details, I think. When you say "change anything", what are you referring to? Please give an example of an action that causes the system to go into a bad state. What Operating System are you running on these older systems? Do you have a detailed list of parts in these systems? If you can give more detail, I might be able to help.

Comment: No video doesn't always have to do with a problem with displays. What you describe sounds like a POST error, which could mean many things. Key thing in a problem when something works and then doesn't is what has changed. As Marc stated above, what did you change that caused the system not to boot? When it fails booting, do you hear any beeps?

Comment: There's a chance these computers are old enough to have a battery to maintain the BIOS settings. If that's the case it's probably dead. There should be a POST (power on self test) failure in that case and you should hear beeps at power up.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing anything really about what is causing this, I would first check for bad caps (capacitors) on the motherboard or video card.  You could also try checking for bad memory with a LiveCD that has memtest86 on it.